# Dynamically-changing variables random intergers

Tags: javascript, string, dynamic, generator, integer

The numbers themselves aren't relevant. I have a list of variables that are used to track a moving vehicle. 
UTC Time:, Latitude:, Longitude:, Speed:, Heading:, Steering:, Odometer:(PPM), GPS Status:, STWS Status:

Like i said the numbers aren't relevant, and neither is the math.  I just need to simulate dynamically changing integers for each variable. For instance, Speed:25. then the 25 become a 26, then a 28, then a 15 and so on.  I will implement this code, and then set the min and max for each variable.
I just need to show customers that the vehicle tracking system monitor can display changing values for each variable.

Thank you.

Comment: Is a device pushing information to your system at some interval? Where is this information displayed? Do you just need a display that continually updates these fields? If so, is there a certain interval for polling the information, i.e. every second, every 30 seconds, etc.?

Comment: James, This is just a simulation, later on we actually will have the embedded system push the data to the machine.  The interface is a web page.  As of right now, I just need to show a mock up of the site, with the numbers changing for each variable to simulate a car driving.  No actual real-time data, just a simulation.

Comment: Okay, and at what interval should these variables be updated?

Comment: Dave looks good, and it does basically what i am needing.  But is there a way for it to remain in a set range of numbers, generate those numbers randomly, and also not have a start button attached? Where do I integrate the $("#the_span_id").text(n); script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#the_span_id").text(n);` and hook it up to a [JavaScript timer event](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Comment: Dave looks good, and it does basically what i am needing. But is there a way for it to remain in a set range of numbers, generate those numbers randomly, and also not have a start button attached? Where do I integrate the $("#the_span_id").text(n); script?

Comment: Use normal JavaScript random number generation like http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp. To start on page load just start the timer when the document's ready. You put the jQuery (please just use it, you'll be better off) code fragment above (along w/ the random number thing) in the timer event handler.

Comment: would you be able to show me an example with one variable? I am not versed in any of this. I am sorry. or at least be a little more specific when you say hook up, and random thing.  I know how to manipulate.  I just need to know how and where to put things so they  can all  reliably depend on one another.

Comment: Dave. Thanks, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is a jQuery countdown. Take a look at this link:

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/04/9-cool-jquery-countdown-scripts.html

Comment: not sure that is what i am looking for, unless you know how to manipulate it.  The number need to update every half second. the number should be random and not in sequence increasing and decreasing in value, like speed of a car in city driving. The variable are within a min max range. Nothing fancy, just changing numbers. i can do it in C with a TCP/IP test board, but need java so I can simulate it on web.

Comment: What's wrong with my answer, then? You can set the text of the span to whatever you want, inside the timer event.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the following lines:

```
var DynVar = {
    variables: [],
    timer: 0,
    numIntervals: 0,
    counter: 0,

    updateVar: function(v) {
        v.value = Math.random() * (v.max - v.min) + v.min;
    },

    createVar: function(name, min, max) {
        var v = {"name": name, "min": min, "max": max};
        DynVar.updateVar(v);
        DynVar.variables.push(v);
        return v;
    },

    update: function() {
        for (i = 0; i < DynVar.variables.length; ++i) {
            var v = DynVar.variables[i];
            DynVar.updateVar(v);
            console.log(DynVar.counter + ": " + v.name + ": " + v.value);
        }
        if (DynVar.counter++ >= DynVar.numIntervals) {
            clearInterval(DynVar.timer);
        }
    },

    start: function(interval, numIntervals) {
        DynVar.counter = 0;
        DynVar.numIntervals = numIntervals;
        DynVar.timer = setInterval(DynVar.update, interval);
    }
};

DynVar.createVar("speed", 10, 30);
DynVar.createVar("latitude", 20, 22);
DynVar.start(1000, 3);
```